# GWT: switching from <table> to g:LayoutPanel and g:layer disable all input

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I'm using uiBinder to layout my views in a gwt project and I've been using a regular table to handle the basic layout of the view. It became kinda messy and static so I was looking into using layers inside a layoutPanel instead. This seemed like a better way of doing it. So before I had the structure:
docklayoutpanel
  center
    tablayoutpanel
      tab
        table
          // tabel rows and cells with various content

and now the table with its rows and columns has been replaced with a layoutPanel with layers. At first it seemed to work fine, looking almost exactly the same (just some margins and padding were off), but then I noticed that all the content inside the layers were completely disabled. Not only buttons and textFields, but I can't even select static text. It's like there's an invisible glass pane over everything. What is causing this and how do I fix it?

Throwing in some code as well. This is what the beginning looked like before (working fine):

```
<g:DockLayoutPanel unit="EM" height="100%">
        <g:center>
            <g:TabLayoutPanel barUnit='EM' barHeight='3'
                ui:field="tabs">
                <!-- TABB 1 -->
                <g:tab>
                    <g:header styleName="viewSubtitleText">
                        <!-- Flikrubrik -->
                        View Person
                    </g:header>
                    <g:LayoutPanel>
                        <g:layer>
                            <g:ScrollPanel>
                                    <g:HTMLPanel>
                                        <table>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td valign="top">
                                                    <g:HTMLPanel styleName="roundedBox">
                                                        <g:HTMLPanel styleName="viewSubtitleText">People</g:HTMLPanel>
                                                        <table>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <table>
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td>
                                                                                <g:HTML>Search </g:HTML>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                            <td>
                                                                                <j:DemiaSuggestBox ui:field="sgtPerson"></j:DemiaSuggestBox>
                                                                            </td>
```

And it was replaced by this:

```
<g:DockLayoutPanel unit="EM" height="100%">
    <g:center>
        <g:TabLayoutPanel barUnit='EM' barHeight='3'
            ui:field="tabs">
            <!-- TABB 1 -->
            <g:tab>
                <g:header styleName="viewSubtitleText">
                    <!-- Flikrubrik -->
                    View Person
                </g:header>
                <g:LayoutPanel>
                    <g:layer styleName="roundedBox">
                        <g:HTMLPanel>
                            <g:HTMLPanel styleName="viewSubtitleText">People</g:HTMLPanel>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <table>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <g:HTML>Search </g:HTML>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <j:DemiaSuggestBox ui:field="sgtPerson"></j:DemiaSuggestBox>
                                                </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out I just forgot to specify the dimension of the layers, e.g:

```
<g:layer left="1em" top="1em" bottom="1em" width="42em">
```